# Oracle Database Configuration Assistant gives Oracle hom user password is not correct error

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

I'm trying to create a new database after installing Oracle Database 18c.

when I get to the second page, I always get an error of [DB T-10304] Oracle home user password is not correct.

I get this no matter what I put in there.

Any suggestions?  thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: Windows 10.  I just added a shot of the previous step

Comment: Invoking the DBCA actually wasn't my first choice.  I actually started out trying to create the database upon initial installation.  I ended up getting the error I just pasted at the end.

Comment: I don't supposed there's a solution for that?  If I could just do it that way I don't think I'd have to mess with the DBCA.

Comment: Rename unzipped folder db_1 or db_home and move into a directory `C:\app\oracle\18.3`.Right click on setup run as administrator step 1 select first option and in step 3   `virtual account` which is default

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm only using Oracle 18c.  I stuck a photo of some instructions I'm looking at that is using 12c.  I'll give that a try now thanks

Comment: Yeah.  Now I'm back to getting the Unable to check whether the location specified is on CFS

Comment: Thanks though - I appreciate the help

Comment: That's odd it's working fine for me.Can you post that screen shot

Comment: Okay - I'm able to get past that error if I just disconnect my computer from the network.  During the final installation, I get a [INS-20802] Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed.

Comment: Are you running setup as administrator?

Comment: Yep. running as an admin

Comment: Thanks Kumar - you've been very helpful.  I'm going to give it a rest for now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue with 12c on Windows Server 2016. Because the Oracle Home user is a local account, review the local security policy and verify that it is not blocking "Local account" from accessing the computer over the network.